I can’t get the top element from the stack (consisting of an element of two child classes)
implementation of the wall class and its child classes, as well as the stack itself.
here I add classes to the stack and using the isBuildingCorrectly function I check whether I can insert the next object, but when I access the fields of the object that is on the stack from the stack, an error is generated
interface.h
class Wall: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    double radiusInside;
    double radiusOutside;
    double Height;
    static int indexNumber;
    static double coordinateZ;
    QString name = "Wall";
    Wall();
    virtual ~Wall();
    friend double GeneratorMonteCarlo();
};

class Disk : public Wall {

public:
    double radiusInside;
    double radiusOutside;
    Disk(double radiusOutside, double radiusInside); // объявляем конструктор
    ~Disk(); // объявляем деструктор
    //const QString name = "Disk";
    int index;
};


class Сylinder : public Wall {

public:
    double radiusOutside;
    double Height;
    Сylinder(double radiusOutside, double height);
    ~Сylinder();
    //const QString name = "Cylinder";
    int index;
};

template <typename T>
class Stack {
private:
  std::stack<T*> elements;
public:
  Stack();
  void push(T* value){
      elements.push(value);
  }

  std::size_t Size() {
      return elements.size();
  }

  T* top() const {
      return elements.top();
  }

  void pop() {
      elements.pop();
  }

  bool empty() const {
      return elements.empty();
  }

  ~Stack() {
      while (!elements.empty()){
          delete elements.top();
         elements.pop();
      }
  }
};

but after the element is added, I cannot access the fields of the object that was added, it throws an exception, but there is a way to output these variables, there will be garbage in them
QString name = stack.top()->name;
if (name == "Cylinder") {
    if ((selected_text == "Cylinder" && val1 == (stack.top()->radiusOutside)) ||
            (selected_text == "Disk" && val1 == (stack.top()->radiusOutside)) ||
            (selected_text == "Disk" && val2 == (stack.top()->radiusInside))) {
           return true;
    }
}


Multiple inheritance is usually not a good idea, read : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance. And why do you wrap std::stack?

I use a stack because in my program logic, in order to add the next element, it needs to be mapped to a physical object, the pop operation that provides a stack is very convenient for this.

In general make a class hierarchy independent of any framework like Qt. Eg. for your Walls and Cylinders make ONE pure abstract baseclass (interface) e.g. IMyObject, for strings just use std::string (not QtString). And then use std::stack<std::unique_ptr<IMyObject>> this will ensure deletion of the pushed object. As it is your code just adds "accidental" complexity. This will keep your business logic seperate from the UI and unit testable.

Could you post the code how you populate your stack?

The error you're encountering is likely due to the use of multiple inheritance and the ambiguity it can cause when accessing members of the base classes.
In your code, both Disk and Cylinder inherit from Wall, and they also have their own data members with the same names as those in Wall (radiusInside, radiusOutside).
When you try to access these members through the base class pointer (stack.top()), C++ doesn't know which version of the member you're referring to, the one in Wall or the one in the derived class (Disk or Cylinder).

How do you advise to solve this problem? There’s simply no other way to do it, I need to add objects of both classes to the stack, is it possible to give each class its own unique fields?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I agree it is generally no good idea to define a member with the same name in the base and derived class. It could be the source of garbage, if one is initialized but the other is read (through pointer to base).
Anyway, this is not called multiple inheritance.

It is a good idea to make a working example and then post it here. Your code does not compile which makes helping you difficult.
In general though, your code is ok. There is no multiple inheritance involved as suggested above, so no problem here.
The only bad idea is testing the string "name" to determine the object you pop from the stack. Better test the object with qobject_cast like this:
Cylinder c(1,2);
Disk d(3,4);
Stack<Wall> s;
s.push(&c);
s.push(&d);
Disk* wd = qobject_cast<Disk*>(s.top());
if (!wd)
{
    qDebug("error no disk");
}
s.pop();
Cylinder* wc = qobject_cast<Cylinder*>(s.top());
if (!wc)
{
    qDebug("error no cylinder");
}
s.pop();
if (!s.empty())
{
    qDebug("error stack not empty");
}

This way, you can delete the name stuff and just work in a type-safe manner with your stack and your objects.
One fat WARNING though: deleting the stack objects in
Stack<Wall>::~Stack() will crash horribly if you push objects from local stack like I did above. Your stack wrapper implementation is very dangerous!
